# Installing a bundle for TextMate

Tags: macos, textmate

I've downloaded the 30 day trial version of TextMate and wanted to use [a plugin for coffeescript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle).

The instructions for installing the plugin say to go to this directory

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles (Textmate 1)
```

Once I changed into the TextMate directory and started looking for Bundles by doing `ls` it only showed

```
TextMate.pid
```

In other words, no Bundles directory....

Once I was in the Bundles directory, I'm supposed to do

```
git clone git://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle CoffeeScriptBundle.tmbundle
```

but didn't want to try that without first being in the Bundles directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new directory in ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/

```
Managed
```

then make another in that directory:

```
Bundles
```

cd to the new directory:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles
```

then run the git in Terminal:

```
git clone git://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle CoffeeScriptBundle.tmbundle
```

Comment: why need to make the Managed directory? may I ask?

Comment: I did this, and restarted TextMate, but don't see any kind of CoffeeScript bundle under the Bundles tab...is that where I'd find it?

Comment: Normally, it should be enough to just create `Bundles` and clone it there, without the `Managed` stuff @m73

Comment: @m73, when I've installed bundles (that have installers),  that is where it saved them. I couldn't tell you why it wouldn't be showing up — you should check the permissions on the bundle, it should be (drwxr-xr-x).

Answer (score 0):

This is all much easier in TextMate 2.

Dozens of bundles are available in the app ( just hit preferences ()⌘,) and the bundle tab…

If by some chance you do need to install a bundle managed in github etc., you can install it right alongside the other bundles, e.g.

~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, **if you are using TextMate 2**, there are multiple ways to acquire/use/edit/manage bundles.

## Installing/Updating bundles

#### Via TextMate's Preferences

A large number of popular bundles (from [TextMate's Github repository](https://github.com/textmate/)) can be installed and managed directly in TextMate via **About > Preferences > Bundles**. By default, these **managed bundles** are automatically updated.

Bundles installed in this way are stored in `$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles` though you should never modify anything under this path.

#### Download and double-click

If you have downloaded some other Textmate bundle (i.e. a directory with a `.tmbundle` extension), you can simply double-click on it to install it into TextMate.  Unlike the managed bundles, these are never automatically updated.  If you want to update to a newer version, you have to manually download it and double-click it to install.

Bundles installed in this way are stored in `$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Pristine Copy/Bundles` though, again, you should never modify anything under this path.

## Modifying bundles

Modifying the bundles described above should only be done within Textmate via **Bundles > Edit Bundles...**.  For those bundles, TextMate stores any changes you make to them as an separate incremental change file, keeping the original bundle intact so that it can be updated without losing your modifications.  These change files are located in a corresponding path under `$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles`.

For example, the **Validate Syntax** command in the managed **PHP** bundle is defined in `$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/PHP.tmbundle/Commands/Validate syntax.plist`.

Upon editing the command via **Bundles > Edit Bundles... > PHP > Menu Actions > Validate Syntax**, TextMate will store your modifications as `$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/PHP.tmbundle/Commands/Validate syntax.plist`

## Creating bundles

New bundles can also be created from within TextMate. Go to **Bundles > Edit Bundles...**, then hit Command-N (⌘N).  After closing the bundle editor and saving your change, your bundle would be created in `$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/`.

**UNLIKE** the managed and pristine (double-clicked) bundles above, changes you make to bundles created this way are stored directly in the bundle source and not as an incremental change file. That means you can also edit the bundle directly from the filesystem if you so choose.

## Installing VCS-managed bundles

Because bundles installed in `$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/` are unmanaged by TextMate (i.e. not auto-updated and not kept as pristine source when changes are made), it's actually the perfect place to install bundles which are managed by external version control systems (e.g. `git`, `svn`, etc)

For example:

```
cd "$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles"
git clone https://github.com/mads-hartmann/Whitespace.tmbundle
```

This would create a bundle directory at:

```
$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Whitespace.tmbundle
```

To use the bundle (or  updates to it after a `git pull`), simply relaunch TextMate (⌃⌘Q).